# how to run pulseaudio systemwide as root on debian?

Tags: debian, root, pulseaudio, alsa

I added these lines into `/etc/systemd/system/pulseaudio.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=PulseAudio system server

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=pulseaudio --daemonize=no --system --realtime --log-target=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Enable service
```

```bash
sudo systemctl --system enable pulseaudio.service
sudo systemctl --system start pulseaudio.service
sudo systemctl --system status pulseaudio.service
```

I edited `/etc/pulse/client.conf` and set the following:

```
default-server = /var/run/pulse/native
autospawn = no
```

Added root to pulse group:

```bash
sudo adduser root pulse-access
```

And finally rebooted the system.

I tried a lot of methods but still fail. Please help me get a working method to run pulseaudio (with alsa utils) as a root systemwide on debian 12 bookworm.

Answer (score 0):

The [Arch-Linux Wiki describes](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio#Starting_system-wide_on_boot) how to start pulseaudio system-wide as root. Disable the user-level PulseAudio service. Edit your `pulseaudio.service` accordingly to documentation.

Note: [What is wrong with system mode?](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/WhatIsWrongWithSystemWide/)